# flink How to deserialize trait to case

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, spray-json

I'm using Flink's(1.7.2) kafka consumer.
How to deserialize several case class that extends the same trait ?
e.g

```
import spray.json.{DefaultJsonProtocol, RootJsonFormat}
  trait Foo
  case class Boo(name: String) extends Foo
  case class Buzz(name: String, age: Int) extends Foo
  object Formats extends DefaultJsonProtocol{
  implicit val booFormat: RootJsonFormat[Boo] = 
       jsonFormat1(Boo.apply)
  implicit val buzzFormat: RootJsonFormat[Buzz] = 
       jsonFormat2(Buzz.apply)
}
```

I'm using kafka consumer with this `DeserializationSchema` :

```
class FooSchema extends DeserializationSchema[Foo]{
  @transient lazy val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  implicit val typeInfo = createTypeInformation[Foo]

  override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): Foo = {
      val foo = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).parseJson
        .convertTo[Foo] //doesn't compile, I need to deserialize to Boo and Buzz
      log.debug(s"Received Boo")
      foo

  }
  override def isEndOfStream(t: Foo): Boolean = false
  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[Foo] = createTypeInformation[Foo]
}
```

any idea will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try [spray-json-shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/spray-json-shapeless) which can automatically derive decoders for ADTs like so:

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Boo(name: String) extends Foo
case class Buzz(name: String, age: Int) extends Foo

object MyFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol with FamilyFormats {
  implicit val formats = shapeless.cachedImplicit[JsonFormat[Foo]]
}
```

Remember to make the trait `sealed`. Note that raw JSON needs to contain `type` field [disambiguator](https://github.com/milessabin/spray-json-shapeless/blob/1ea48c8f571ecca29231238c5ed79eb7d7514fdb/src/test/scala/fommil/sjs/FamilyFormatsSpec.scala#L174) for `rawJsonString.parseJson.convertTo[Foo]` to work, for example

```
  object Main extends App {
    import MyFormats._

    val rawJsonBuzz =
      """
        |{
        |  "name": "Picard",
        |  "age": 60,
        |  "type": "Buzz"
        |}
      """.stripMargin

    val buzz = rawJsonBuzz.parseJson.convertTo[Foo]
    println(buzz)

    val rawJsonBoo =
      """
        |{
        |  "name": "Picard",
        |  "type": "Boo"
        |}
      """.stripMargin

    val boo = rawJsonBoo.parseJson.convertTo[Foo]
    println(boo)
  }
```

should output

```
Buzz(Picard,60)
Boo(Picard)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mario, I understand that this will define the format to all sub case classes but how do I "read" if I simply do now `val foo = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).parseJson
        .convertTo[Foo]` I will get runtime exception

Comment: Thanks !!! I see that I missed the `type` field. it seems that it kind of adding some unrelated concerns to the client. I was kind of hoping for something that will do it with some pattern matching or something like that, without cluttering the message